# Pull an external page 10 seconds after the request using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, parsing

I have two web pages that I'll call `domain.com/Alvin` and `domain.com/Bert` for this example.

Alvin displays search results based on a query string variable, but it loads the results using JavaScript approximately two seconds after the page loads.

Bert needs to use these results for occasional ad-hoc reporting, but due to the way the company is set up, I can't link directly into the database that Alvin is pulling from. A different team manages the Alvin page, so I won't have access to change their existing code.

While I think I could do this with .NET, I'm unsure of how to do the request with PHP which is highly preferred for the page.

Is anybody aware of how I could use `file_get_contents`, `file_get_html` or any other PHP functions to get the HTML of another page but only pull the HTML five seconds after the initial request to allow the JavaScript to update the results?

Comment: Javascript is client side, your main issue would be trying to get PHP to even run it. file_get_contents will grab all of the text for the site, this includes the javascript, but it will never run it.

Comment: Well it sounds like javascript is going to be the layer in which you will need the logic for handling loading content from one page and then another.  Not sure PHP really has anything to do with this other than its use in serving up the contents being pulled into the page.

Comment: If the results are per-user, you can store the results in a session and have page B check periodically. Otherwise you could use a text file to store the results that the ajax request generates.

Comment: Since they are on the same domain, one page can ajax the other page in

Comment: Can't you make the same ajax call that page A is making?

Comment: Does the first page use JavaScript just to load the data, or is there is extra page decoration/rendering in JavaScript? You can do the AJAX loading in the second page, but if you want to copy a page after JS has processed it, you _might_ be able to do this in an `iframe` embedded on the second page (and only by virtue of the two sharing a domain). It's a bit inelegant though, and of course it is better to collaborate with the Alvin team so they provide a clean AJAX API that gives you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to mplungjan - not sure why I didn't think of this earlier, but I was able to replicate the AJAX to the same request. Thanks!

> Since they are on the same domain, one page can ajax the other page in –  **mplungjan**